# PHP - foreach to create array - data being overwritten

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array like the following, but this time dynamically

```
$taInputs = array(
    "fieldOne" => array($this->fieldOne, '0,166,198'),
    "fieldTwo" => array($this->fieldTwo, '0,166,198'),
    "fieldThree" => array($this->fieldThree, '0,166,198'),
    "fieldFour" => array($this->fieldFour, '0,166,198')
);
```

So, I create my Array Object

```
$this->data = array();
```

And then I have the following loop

```
foreach($this->document->documentData as $documentData)
{
    $this->data = array(
        $documentData->key => array($documentData->value, '228,47,57')
    );
}
```

At the moment, if I output the data array after the foreach loop, I only see the last entry, so it is overwriting it on each loop.

How can I create the array I am after without it being overwritten?

Comment: `$this->data[] = ....` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use PHP's `[]` to set the key on the array.

So, change `$this->data` to `$this->data[ $documentData->key ]`:

```
foreach($this->document->documentData as $documentData)
{
    $this->data[$documentData->key] = array($documentData->value, '228,47,57');
}
```

Without the variables you can manually set it like this:

```
$this->data[ 'fieldOne' ] = array('someValue', '228,47,57');
$this->data[ 'fieldTwo' ] = array('someValue', '228,47,57');
$this->data[ 'fieldThree' ] = array('someValue', '228,47,57');
$this->data[ 'fieldFour' ] = array('someValue', '228,47,57');
```

Then you can iterate over those values with:

```
foreach ($this->data as $key => $data) {
    print "$key => $data[0], $data[1]";
}
```

Usually you will want to define it like this because accessing an array by a key number is kind of annoying:

```
$this->data[ 'fieldOne' ] = array('documentValue' => 'someValue', 'myNumber' => '228,47,57');
```

So that you can easily access it with the documentValue or myNumber key:

```
echo $this->data['fieldOne']['documentValue'];
echo $this->data['fieldOne']['myNumber'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this

```
foreach($this->document->documentData as $documentData)
{
    $this->data[$documentData->key] = array($documentData->value, '228,47,57');    

}
```